# Basic Series Question: From $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$ to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n = \frac{z}{1-z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am stuck on not being to see how the summation of the series goes from $1/(1-z)$ to $z/(1-z)$ from the index shift.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n$ is just $\displaystyle\sum_{n=}^\infty z^n$ without $z^0$, which is $1$. Hence, it's value is $\frac{1}{1-z} - 1 = \frac{z}{1-z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $z\sum_{n\geq0}z^{n}=\sum_{n\geq0}z^{n+1}=\sum_{n\geq1}z^{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply every term in the first series by $z$. How does this change the left- and right- hand sides?